# How many twists and turns can a vent pipe take?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, venting

I'm replacing a bathtub in the basement and by the looks of it, its trap is not vented. I want to know if I can put a vent pipe in the location I've identified as most feasible and secondly, if it's not too far away to tie into an existing vent pipe.

Here is a picture of the plumbing and a direct shot of where the tub will go. The tub sits right up against the 3" horizontal pipe.

## 1.

Can I put a horizontal tee in the horizontally running 3" waste pipe?

## 2.

Can I bring a vent pipe up ~5 feet, horizontal 5 feet over and then a 90 degree turn, run horizontal 2 feet to tie into an existing vent? How many twists and turns are too many for a vent pipe? If I can't go this route to tie into the existing vent, but going up vertically from the 3" is OK, then I guess I could use an AAV, which are allowed here in Ontario Canada.

[image]

Comment: What are the other fixtures draining upstream into that 3" horizontal pipe?

Comment: A toilet, shower and sink